# Error in loading SASS stylesheet

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, sass, slim-lang

I am experimenting with SASS and am trying to load a simple sytlesheet using scss in my sinatra application.

The route handler in main.rb is

```
get('/styles.css'){ scss :styles }
```

In the layout (using the slim view renderer), I am using the css file as:

```
    link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"
```

I've removed the stylesheet from public folder and created the styles.scss inside the views folder, but am unable to get the css file in the rendered page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
The main problem was that I had an error in the sass file which caused it to fail silently.
on searching for the generated css file at `http://localhost:4567/styles.css`, the error was reported. On a hover option, `&:hover {
            background: darken($background, 20%);`
 I had a $ in place of the '&' symbol.